# How to use Progress Bar Form button click events when data is loading in my class

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-forms-designer

I have a class to load some data from a file and a progress bar form to show the process. My class uses a for loop to load data with a selected buffer size and sets the progress bar value in each loop.

I want to add a cancel and pause button to my form, but when my class starts loading data, the form buttons dont work.

I tried using different threads but they can't have access to same element.

How can I make it so that buttons work when data is loading?

Note: user can select the read type so there are different methods for each type(double,int,byte)
here is my load function:

```cs
for (int count = 0; count < (FileSize / LoadBufferSize); count++)
{
    if (_check_click == 2)
    {
        return convertedData;
    }
    else if(_check_click==1)
    {
        return new Int16[1];
    }
    else
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                fileContent[i] = br.ReadInt16();
            }
            catch (EndOfStreamException)
            {
                loadflag = 1;
                contentSize = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < contentSize; k += ReSampleRate)
        {
            try
            {
                convertedData[(count * fileContent.Length / ReSampleRate) + j] = fileContent[k];
                j++;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("could not load the file completely");
                goto lable;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("something went wrong");
            }
        }

        progress = ((count + 1) * fileContent.Length ) / (FileSize / 100);
        barForm.SetBar((int)progress);
    }
}
lable:
{
    return convertedData;
}
```

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?888203-Modal-Wait-Dialogue-with-BackgroundWorker) out. I fancy that it's a better way to do what you want. It already implements progress and cancellation. You just have to be able to measure progress appropriately, which I'm guessing you can already do.

Comment: Please never ever write `catch { MessageBox.Show("something went wrong"); }`.

Comment: Oh, and `goto` - never ever ever use that.

Comment: You also seem to have difficulty with integer math.

Comment: I used goto in c# twice in 20yrs . it's not entirely useless. But not in this case

Comment: @Enigmativity i will try to make my coding better. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Queue<string> _items = new Queue<string>(new [] { "A", "B", "C" });

    private Button _startButton = new Button() { Text = "Start", Top = 8, Left = 4, Height = 24, Width = 100 };
    private Button _pauseButton = new Button() { Text = "Pause", Top = 32, Left = 4, Height = 24, Width = 100 };
    private bool _paused = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        _startButton.Click += (s, e) => this.Process();
        _pauseButton.Click += (s, e) => _paused = true;
        this.Controls.Add(_startButton);
        this.Controls.Add(_pauseButton);
    }

    private void Process()
    {
        if (!_paused && _items.TryDequeue(out string text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            this.Invoke(() => this.Process());
        }
    }
}
```

The key thing here is that the `private void Process()` method has a recursive call to itself ***through the `.Invoke` method***. This keeps running `Process` so long as there are items in the queue, but it also lets other events occur in the meanwhile, so if someone clicks the `Pause` button then the `Process` method will stop running.

There is no `for` loop. Just a repeating `Process` method that responds to any changes in state.